# Does the use of Flurry or Localytics with Mono necessarily imply that two separate implementations will be needed for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, mono, flurry, localytics

I intend to use either Flurry or Localytics for performing analytics on my mobile app. I am developing in Mono. The point of Mono is that your source code doesn't need to change and you can develop applications for both iOS and Android with the same source code. But, I found that Flurry and Localytics code is platform dependent. So this seems to destroy my purpose of using the same source code for both Android and iPhone. Is this correct? Is there a workaround that I can use? And no, I am not intending to use Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a bridge class to switch between the two implementations, but the remainder of your code should stay cross-platform compatible.  You may also need to make your API calls dynamically, since you may not be able to bind the "foreign" library statically.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a developer on the Localytics team working on the client libraries. The answer is that yes, it does ultimately require different implementations, as there are some differences in the Android and iOS library. As Robert's suggested, you may want to build your own platform  abstraction class.